# Set Lookup and User Field Types when Migrating to Sharepoint online using Migration API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfield, migrationapi

I am in the process of writing a c# code to migrate set of files to Sharepoint online(o365) using migration API and I have successfully done migration using the approach mentioned in the below link.

http://case.schollaart.net/2016/03/10/office365-migration-using-c-sharp.html

But I am unable to update complex field types such as Lookup fields and User type fields in a document library.

Is there any suggestion or approach recommended for this scenario?

Comment: I have found that lookup fields can be updated using the respective lookup ID and User Types should be resolved by creating UserGroup.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that lookup fields can be updated using the respective lookup ID and User Types should be resolved by creating UserGroup.xml.

UserGroup.xml should contain all the users that needs to be resolved with the respective details.

Lookup ID's should be passed to set the lookup field values.